# Perl - Open file - Last line is missing if newline is not presented after last line

Tags: perl, file-io

Hello can somebody please explain me why I have different output from following two scripts:

**01.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

open FDGROUP, "< file" or die "Can't open file: $!\n";
my @file = <FDGROUP>;
close FDGROUP;

@file = grep {/\S/} @file;

@file = grep {s/\r//} @file;
@file = grep {s/\n//} @file;

print Dumper @file;
```

**02.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

open FDGROUP, "< file" or die "Can't open file: $!\n";
my @file = <FDGROUP>;
close FDGROUP;

@file = grep {/\S/} @file;

my $j = 0;
foreach (@file){
  $_ =~ s/\r//;
  $_ =~ s/\n//;
  $file[$j++] = $_;
}

print Dumper @file;
```

**Output:**

```
wakatana@azureus ~/scripts/stackoverflow
$ perl 01.pl
$VAR1 = '1';
$VAR2 = '2';
$VAR3 = '3';
$VAR4 = '4';
$VAR5 = '5';
$VAR6 = '6';

wakatana@azureus ~/scripts/stackoverflow
$ perl 02.pl
$VAR1 = '1';
$VAR2 = '2';
$VAR3 = '3';
$VAR4 = '4';
$VAR5 = '5';
$VAR6 = '6';
$VAR7 = '7';

wakatana@azureus ~/scripts/stackoverflow
$ od -ab file
0000000   1  cr  nl   2  cr  nl   3  cr  nl   4  cr  nl   5  cr  nl   6
        061 015 012 062 015 012 063 015 012 064 015 012 065 015 012 066
0000020  cr  nl   7
        015 012 067
0000023

wakatana@azureus ~/scripts/stackoverflow
$ perl -e 'print $/' | od -ab
0000000  nl
        012
0000001
```

When I add another newline after last line in file which I am opening the scripts gives same results (7 variables). I know that `chomp` is used for such operations but when I used following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

open FDGROUP, "< file" or die "Can't open file: $!\n";
my @file = <FDGROUP>;
close FDGROUP;

@file = grep {/\S/} @file;
chomp @file;
print Dumper @file;
```

I get following output:

```
wakatana@azureus ~/scripts/stackoverflow
$ perl 03.pl
';AR1 = '1
';AR2 = '2
';AR3 = '3
';AR4 = '4
';AR5 = '5
';AR6 = '6
';AR7 = '7
```

Probably this is caused by CR white-space or something with it.

All this is done under under cygwin.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With these statements:

```perl
@file = grep {/\S/} @file; # strips any element which doesn't have non-whitespace characters
@file = grep {s/\r//} @file; # strips any elem which doesn't have a \r, strips \r from those that do
@file = grep {s/\n//} @file; # strips any elem which doesn't have a \n, strips \n from those that do
```

Each time you're building a new array. That new array consists of all the elements of the input to `grep` which match the given `{ block }`.

With the last line missing its `\n`, it'll leave out that line.

Comment: Oh, I cannot see the forest for the trees. Thanks for clarifying. Is it possible to write it using more elegant (grep or something other) way?

Comment: Tried following but did not give expected results: @file = grep {s/\s$// || $_} @file;

Comment: Assuming you want to filter out empty lines and strip CR/LF, `@file = grep { s/^(.*?)\r?\n?$/$1/ && length } @file` will work for both Windows and Linux. There are (many) other ways to achieve the same thing though.

Answer (score 1):

Grep only works if it matches the expression. The last line doesn't have \n so it doesn't return a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24890193/3755747 not technically an answer to what you're really asking ... but your code is quite an old style Perl, so here are a few more modern alternatives for you.

Fully written out, basic Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer; # I prefer this over Data::Dumper

open( my $fh, '<', 'file' ) or die "can't open 'file': $!";

my @lines;
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    $line =~ s/^(.*?)\r?\n?$/$1/;
    next if $line eq '';
    push @lines, $line;
}
close $fh or die "can't close 'file': $!";

p( @lines );
```

A very compact version, but with explanation:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;

my @lines = grep {
    s/
        ^         # start of string
          (.*?)   # capture non-greedy match, without the ? it consumes the \r and \n as well
          \r? \n? # optional CR, optional LF
        $         # end of string
     /$1/x        # replace with the match, whitespace allowed in regex
    && length     # and string has to have some length remaining
} read_file( 'file' );

p( @lines );
```

Different way, using `split`:

```
use Modern::Perl '2012';
use File::Slurp;
use Data::Printer;

# added parenthesis around split arguments for clarity, they're not needed
my @lines = grep { length } split( /\r?\n/, read_file 'file' );
p( @lines );
```

Slurping is perfectly possible without modules as well:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Printer;

open( my $fh, '<', 'file' ) or die "can't open 'file': $!";
my @lines = grep { s/^(.*?)\r?\n?$/$1/ && length } <$fh>;
close $fh or die "can't close 'file': $!";

p( @lines );
```

I think I prefer the `split` version.